# Creating a Django model ForeignKey field from a specific queryset?

Tags: django, django-models

Ok, this is a hard one to explain.

I Have these models:

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    costprice = models.FloatField(null=True, max_length=99, blank=True)
    retailprice = models.FloatField(null=True, max_length=99, blank=True)
    barcode = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=99, unique=True, blank=True)
    image = DefaultStaticImageField(null=True, blank=True,default='images/item_gC0XXrx.png')
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_qty = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to create an 'Order' pulling items from a specific supplier.

Now, I have no idea as to make that happen - how do I create an instance of an 'Order',in a form of some sort, that will fetch items from the selected supplier and not all items from everybody else?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)

Comment: And if that doesn't suffice, you need to override `get_queryset` method of your form field. For example look at this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

Comment: Thanks, however I dont see how I can apply this to my use case

Comment: D you want to limit your choices in django admin?

Comment: I want to choose a supplier from a list, then from that particular supplier, choose only the items associated with it, in a view. When I choose 'supplier x', only items carried by supplier x should be available to choose from... hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you want to select both supplier and item in a single page, you need to write some js. You should listen to changes of supplier field and after supplier has been selected, you should fetch items related to that supplier and view them as the options of your order's item.